# React router switch defaults to final redirect

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, ts-jest

I'm writing unit tests using ts-jest for a React Component that renders a react router switch. It performs the following:

1. Redirect the user to "/dashboard" if the URL path is "/home".
2. Render App1 component if the URL path is "/app1".
3. Redirect the user to "/404" if the URL path is not #1 or #2.

Here's the code for how I'm setting up the test

```
//src/__test__/mycomponent.spec.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import MyComponent from '../components/MyComponent';

describe('MyComponent redirects from /home correctly', () => {
  it('should change route to "/dashboard" when "/home" route is detected', () => {
    const history = createBrowserHistory();
    history.replace('/home');
    render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <MyComponent />
      </Router>,
    );
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/dashboard');
  });
});
```

However, my test fails. Jest tells me that `history.location.pathname` is "/404".

Here's the code for MyComponent

```
// src/components/MyComponent.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App1 from './App1';

const MyComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Redirect from="/home" to="/dashboard" />
      <Route path="/app1">
          <App1 />
      </Route>
      <Redirect to="/404" />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

I noticed when I remove the redirect to 404 from MyComponent.tsx, my test would pass. However, as soon as I add it back, it would fail so I have narrowed down the issue to the final redirect component.

When I tried changing the path in my test to "/app1", I was able to verify that the URL path was indeed changed to /app1 and the component successfully renders.

It appears to me that there's something wrong with the way switch processes redirect even when a match occurs.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried using MemoryRouter to test these? Using Router may cause complications since it is a lower level abstraction.

Comment: It's interesting you mentioned this. I dug around and found this testing guide from react-router project itself (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/testing.md) I tried the memory router method and got the same result.

Comment: Upon reflection on my last comment, react-router states that unit tests have been written for the components provided by the library; Testing of location changes is not really needed. The only verification, if any, would be on the contents rendered once the location has changed. With that in mind, I think I should not be testing redirect routes as those are components of the library and only testing the routes being rendered, to which the App1 case has been proven to work. Do you agree with this perspective?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would do. Assert <component> exists given <MyComponent at path XYZ>.